# Animating 2d joints using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, computer-vision, data-science

I wanted to animate a set of keypoints extracted from yolov7 pose. Each frames contains keypoints in it.

Here is an example of my data construction. Its a 2D Numpy array that contains a list of x and y coordinates for each joints.

```
[[423.25  255.5  ]
 [244.5   409.25 ]
 [453.    254.5  ]
 [222.875 450.25 ]
 [315.25  277.   ]
 [408.    320.75 ]
 [467.    418.75 ]
 [425.25  412.25 ]
 [311.    431.75 ]
 [410.25  371.25 ]
 [420.    413.5  ]]
```

Here is the code in my attempt to animate my skeletal features:

```
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

def animate_skel(frames):
    steps = 3
    fig = plt.figure()
    l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r.', markersize= 10)
    metadata = {'title': "sample", "artist": "sample"}
    writer = PillowWriter(fps= 3, metadata= metadata)


    with writer.saving(fig, 'skeletal_frame.gif', 100):
        for pose in frames:
            x_coords = []
            y_coords = []
            num_kpts = len(pose) // steps
            for kid in range(num_kpts):
                x_coord, y_coord = pose[steps*kid], pose[steps*kid+1]
                if not (x_coord % 640 == 0 or y_coord % 640 == 0):
                    if steps == 3:
                        conf = pose[steps*kid+2]
                        if conf < 0.5:
                            continue
                    x_coords.append(x_coord)
                    y_coords.append(y_coord)
            l.set_data(x_coords, y_coords)
            writer.grab_frame()
    return

animate_skel(arr)
```

Tried running my code. It ran but did not show the joints on the figure. Hoping that someone can help me with this. Big thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue arises because `len(pose)` is always 2, and then `num_kpts = 2 // 3 = 0` follows.